# How to get actual position of the object?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, velocity.js

i have following code snippet which is trying to get actual position of the animated object each 100 ms.

```
   $scope.getPositionOfTheSpiderOnTheRope = function() {
        $interval(function () {
           var positionOfTheSpider =  $('#spiderTwo').position();
           console.log(positionOfTheSpider.top);
        }, 100);
    }
```

Function for animation is following:

```
$scope.animateSpiderOne = function () {
        $('#spiderTwo').velocity({
            "margin-top": '+=20%',
        }, 4500, function () {
            console.log("MOVE DOWN END");
            $('#spiderTwo').velocity({
                "margin-top": '-=20%',
            }, 4500, function () {
                console.log("MOVE UP END");
                $scope.animateSpiderOne();
            });
        });
    };
```

Problem is that animation is animating but returned value is still same without change.

How can i solve it please?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.position()` method doesn't take `margin` into account. If you animate `top` instead of `margin-top` you'll get a different value.

Comment: You can animate top instead of margin-top, just replace the two in the .velocity() calls

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this code snippet :

```
   $scope.getPositionOfTheSpiderOnTheRope = function() {
               var positionOfTheSpider =  $('#spiderTwo');
               console.log(positionOfTheSpider[0].style.marginTop);
        }
```